# f string provides invalid syntax error only on an ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, discord

This code functions perfectly well on my computer, but when used on the droplet server, it provides me with an invalid Syntax Error. Why I swap from F string to %, it doesn't message the channel that I need. I'm at a loss as to how to fix this, and would appreciate any help provided.

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    chan1 = client.get_channel('505801900361515008')
    chan2 = client.get_channel('505801944707760138')
    chan3 = client.get_channel('506194214309068800')
    print (message.content)
    if not  message.server and message.content.startswith('apply'):
        await client.send_message(author, 'Your application has been forwarded to the Department of Studies and Development! Enjoy our anime, and off topic channels while youre around!')
        await client.send_message(chan1, f'{author.mention} has applied for membership, so please hurry back with a response! Content:  {message.content}')
    elif not  message.server and message.content.startswith('diplo'):
        await client.send_message(author, 'Your message has been forwarded to the Department of Investigation! Enjoy our anime, and off topic channels while youre around!')
        await client.send_message(chan2, f'{author.mention} has applied for a diplomat mask, so please hurry back with a response! Content:  {message.content}') 
    elif not  message.server and message.content.startswith('req'):
        await client.send_message(author, 'Your message has been forwarded to the Department of Resource Procurement! The staffers will react to the message with a green checkmark when its been processed.')
        await client.send_message(chan3, f'{author.mention} has made an economic request, so please hurry back with a response! Content:  {message.content}')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: If the server is not running Python 3.6+ it will not support f-strings that's why it'll throw a `SyntaxError`.  Perhaps try `str.format()` instead?

Comment: Probably you did not upgrade to Python-3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Your local machine is running >= python 3.6

Your droplet is running < python 3.6

F strings are python 3.6 and above.

So you can either downgrade your virtual environment in your local machine or upgrade the droplet.

Downgrading the virtual environment would probably be quicker:

`virtualenv .venv -p python3.6`

Then use str.format instead of f strings